# Why can't I find text when using the multiprocessing module in blender?

Tags: python, scripting, error

I wrote a multiprocessing module to extract one of the selected bones and perform the task of finding the closest bone.

```
import bpy
import multiprocessing

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
seleb_n = [i.name for i in bpy.context.selected_editable_bones]

actob_n = bpy.context.active_object.name
#head_bn : {tail_bn : distance}
headtail_dic = multiprocessing.Manager().dict()


# if i input bone_name, then process find the most nearest tail of bone to head
def find_nearest_head_co(actob_n, bn, bn_l):
    target_vector = bpy.data.objects[actob_n].data.edit_bones[bn].head
    for fbn in bn_l:
        tail_vector = bpy.data.objects[actob_n].data.edit_bones[fbn].tail
        distance = ((target_vector[0]-tail_vector[0])**1/2 + (target_vector[1]-tail_vector[1])**1/2 + (target_vector[2]-tail_vector[2])**1/2)**1/2
        headtail_dic[bn] = {fbn:distance}
        print(headtail_dic[bn])

jobs = []
for bn in seleb_n:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=find_nearest_head_co, args=(actob_n, bn, seleb_n))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()

for proc in jobs:
    proc.join()

print(headtail_dic)
```

When I run the script, the error message is displayed on the terminal:

```
'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\script_name'
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: Blender Python doesn't support multithreaded operation. You can use multiprocessing to do stuff outside of Blender, but you can't access the project in multiple processes. You could perhaps run separate Blender instances and open the same file in each of them, but I don't see anything like that in your code.